# Django not loading the template completely

Tags: django, cloud9-ide

I am creating a web app using Django 1.6. I have a question about the "time-out" issue of Django.

I created a template with javascript and css in it for visual effects. Occasionally, I found my visual effect supported by javascript and css to be messed up (e.g. the `<div>` element should resized according to screen, but it just did not resize). I checked the source of the page and found that the bottom part of my html file was not there (some line in the `<script>` was cut abruptly at the bottom of my page). I think that is the reason on why the visual effect sometimes cannot be seen.

I am using `Cloud9` for developing my app. I wonder whether it is `Cloud9` or `Django` itself causing the interrupted transmission of HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a content-length issue. It's possibly a bug in Cloud9. If so, contact support@c9.io. You can verify the content-length header in the network tab of your browser. You can verify there whether it matches up to the content sent.